# Movement of rectangle with tot function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, rectangles

How can I make this rectangle move from the top left down to the bottom right?

```
clear all
close all
clc
n=10;
h=1;
for t=0:n-1
    clf;
    axis([0 sum(1:n) 0 sum(1:n)]);
    axis manual
    tot = sum(0:t);
    patch([tot tot+(t+1)*h tot+(t+1)*h tot],[tot tot tot+(t+1)*h tot+(t+1)*h],...
        [2 6 3 7],'EdgeColor','none','FaceAlpha',(1-(t+1)*.7/n));
    pause(1/6)
end
```

Also, try to use this function somewhere.
`sum(1:t)-tot-(t+1)*h`

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped you, to confirm the topic is close.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the Y location for patch function differently, but from your current code, the simplest change will be to reverse the Y axis direction:

```
axis ij; % put this before patch
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to substruct your `y` coordinates from the total height `sum(0:n)`:

```
patch([tot tot+(t+1)*h tot+(t+1)*h tot],...
    sum(0:n)-[tot tot tot+(t+1)*h tot+(t+1)*h],...
    [2 6 3 7],'EdgeColor','none','FaceAlpha',(1-(t+1)*.7/n));
```